# Why can't I write to recovery using fastboot on A/B device?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, fastboot, ab-partition, mi-a2

I'm trying to flash TWRP Recovery into my `Mi A2` recovery. However I get the error when flashing:

```
~$ fastboot flash recovery twrp.img
FAILED (remote: '(recovery_a) No such partition')
```

Does anyone know how to fix this error? I did test flashing it to `boot_b`, and that did work. but that's not the recovery slot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's expected. Devices with `A/B` partition scheme don't have a recovery partition. You can only boot in recovery mode with `fastboot boot twrp.img`. But to permanently flash recovery to device which can be booted into by proper key combination, you need to unpack both of your `boot.img`s (A/B) from device and replace the `ramdisk` with the one extracted from `twrp.img`. Then repack and flash `boot.img`s back to device.

On TWRP this has  been previously achieved by flashing a special ZIP file, or one could do manually. Now the official TWRP [release](https://twrp.me/site/update/2019/04/15/twrp-3.3.0-0-released.html) includes the option `Install Recovery Ramdisk`:

> Use magiskboot to allow repacking boot images for installing TWRP

Traditionally `boot.img` and `recovery.img` had two major components; kernel and ramdisk. On A/B devices, no ramdisk is required for normal boot because `system.img` is mounted as `rootfs` when processing Device Tree (`dtb`) which is appended to kernel image usually. So the `ramdisk.cpio` in `boot.img` is that of recovery. Since kernel is same for a device (other than build configurations), so only ramdisk needs to be replaced.

**Sources:**

- [Implementing A/B Updates](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/ab/ab_implement#recovery)
- [System-as-root](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/system-as-root#about-system-as-root)

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea.

Comment: In layman terms: first flash TWRP image into your phone via fastboot and this command `fastboot boot twrp.img`, once you booted on recovery mode (TWRP), use it to install TWRP permanently via the zip for your phone