# Twrp recovery for mtk6763 (a/b) infinix note 5

Tags: recovery-mode, data-recovery, clockworkmod-recovery, mediatek

Please i need help so much.
My device dont have developers, and we don't have any custom recovery for this device, i don't have any idea to port twrp since recovery included in boot.img, also i don't know anything about compiling from source, i finind smaller guide to port but didnt find tool working well.
So please if someone may help to build or port.
There kernel source available for our device but no device tree.
Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following this [tutorial](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-21970.html) to create a ROM dump of your device. Take the recovery.img from that dump and create a TWRP using [this](https://forum.hovatek.com/thread-21839.html).

If you already have the recovery.img you can proceed right to the second link.

Comment: please note tutorials are for older devices. i guess the question is more about this
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209673
temporary root shell may helpful to get a backup of stock boot/recovery ramdisk from device
https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/development/amazing-temp-root-mediatek-armv8-t3922213

Comment: That's true the TWRP Porter only goes up to Oreo. There is further information on what to do if you have a more recent Android version. They also have a great support forum at Hovatek. If it's root your looking for you can root without TWRP. I've done it with Magisk: https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/root-recovery-root-device-magisk-t3779454 but you would still need the boot image. The first link above can help you get that.