# Installing rom zip through TWRP replaces recovery instead of intalling os

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, lineageos, ab-partition

I formatted my Oneplus 6t and was able to install TWRP, but when I install the zip for LineageOS, instead of installing it as the OS, it just replaces the TWRP recovery with a Lineage one, and I am still unable to boot into system. 
[Log.txt](https://pastebin.com/a48GQYFJ)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I write to recovery using fastboot on A/B device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209673/why-cant-i-write-to-recovery-using-fastboot-on-a-b-device)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright I actually figured it out: the trick is to flash the stock ROM using [this tool](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-6t/how-to/rom-stock-fastboot-roms-oneplus-6t-t3862516) and then fastboot TWRP, install the TWRP and then install Lineage all without formatting the internal storage. I don't know why that works, but it does.