# Trying to root Pixel XL

Tags: twrp, bootloader

I'm trying to root a Pixel XL in order to use 'su' in an adb shell to run gdbserver.
I've unlocked a few other phones to do this but the process seems a little different now or it is for this particular phone.
I've followed the instructions at 'https://www.online-tech-tips.com/smartphones/how-to-root-a-pixel-xl-2-2xl-3-3xl/' but I'm stuck at the command 'fastboot boot twrp.img'.
I downloaded the version of TWRP for my device (twrp-pixel-installer-marlin-3.3.0-0) but there's no file called 'twrp.img' in there. There's not even a file with a '.img' extension, just these:

```
magiskboot
META-INF
ramdisk-twrp.cpio
```

Now, I'm a bit overly cautious when it comes to flashing a mobile phone and I don't want to put a bunch of junk in my bootloader, so what should I do here? It's not particularly clear (and when it comes to potentially bricking things, I very much like things to be clear).

Comment: Why do you download the installer from 2019 if you want the image from 2021?

Comment: Like @Robert said you have the latest (April this year) released zip adm img files here https://dl.twrp.me/marlin/

Comment: Ok, so the list wasn't sorted by date, they changed the naming convention for some reason and I missed the later files: oops.
However, opening up 
twrp-installer-3.5.2_9-0-marlin.zip
reveals exactly the same problem.

magiskboot
META-INF
ramdisk-twrp.cpio

nothing with .img in there that I can see.  Is that 'cpio' file the same as an img file? It's not something I'd like to guess.

Comment: Why are you opening zip file - there are `twrp.img` files in the same list. This looks to be the latest https://dl.twrp.me/marlin/twrp-3.5.2_9-0-marlin.img.html

Comment: I opened the zip files because that's typically what you do with zip files.  If the img files are a direct download, what are the zip files for?
Like I said, apologies if I'm appearing dense here but I'm super cautious when flashing the phone, I don't want to make any mistakes.

Comment: Please read the full page before downloading something. There are three different types of downloads on this site.

Comment: Ok, I didn't realise that. I don't recall having to use TWRP for rooting with other phones, although it looks like a useful program that should help my android dev work. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: indeed the sorting of download list is quite confusing, scroll down for twrp.img

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I write to recovery using fastboot on A/B device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/209673/why-cant-i-write-to-recovery-using-fastboot-on-a-b-device)