# How to extract the stock recovery for HTC M8s? Do I even need it if I have the full RUU package?

Tags: recovery-mode, stock-rom, htc-one-m8

While I'm currently fully on stock, is there any way to extract the stock recovery now, before I replace it with TWRP? Do I even need to do that if I have entire RUU zip or will recovery be restored when I flash the ZIP through htc_fastboot?

I have seen links to ruu.lalleman.net with stock recoveries and RUUs, but the links are dead now.

My HTC M8s is fully stock now and I want to try Lineage 15.1 from https://src.voidzero.net/ (unless you can suggest some even more stable ROM with at least Android 7). I found twrp-3.2.3-0-m8qlul.img also on the same website, and also MindTheGapps-8.1.0-arm-20180808_153837.zip, so it should all work together nicely (I hope).

But before I go on, I want to make sure I can return back to stock. So, I have obtained RUU 0PKVIMG_M8_QL_UL_M60_SENSE70_MR_HTC_Europe_2.21.401.1_Radio_1.0.U20410.1@60201_20.05_018_F_release_496316_signed_2_4.zip that matches my radio number and currently installed mainver number. However, I can't find the stock recovery anywhere.

Here's my fastboot info:

```
fastboot getvar all
(bootloader) version: 0.5
(bootloader) version-bootloader: 3.19.0.0000
(bootloader) version-baseband: 1.0.U20410.1@60201
(bootloader) version-cpld: None
(bootloader) version-microp: None
(bootloader) version-main: 2.21.401.1
(bootloader) version-misc: PVT SHIP S-ON
(bootloader) serialno: -
(bootloader) imei: -
(bootloader) imei2: Not Support
(bootloader) meid: 00000000000000
(bootloader) product: m8ql_ul
(bootloader) platform: hTCBmsm8939
(bootloader) modelid: 0PKV10000
(bootloader) cidnum: HTC__001
(bootloader) battery-status: good
(bootloader) battery-voltage: 0mV
(bootloader) partition-layout: Generic
(bootloader) security: on
(bootloader) build-mode: SHIP
(bootloader) boot-mode: FASTBOOT
(bootloader) commitno-bootloader: 0b9a12e3
(bootloader) hbootpreupdate: 11
(bootloader) gencheckpt: 0
(bootloader) mfg-name: 0001
```

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tool-28-nov-2017-universal-htc-ruu-rom-decryption-tool-3-6-8.3382928

Comment: @alecxs  The RUU zip I got is not encrypted, I can extract all files freely. However, there seems to be no recovery inside. At least, I don't see any recovery.img or anything like that.

Comment: recovery ramdisk in boot? https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209673

Comment: Ask [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/help-thread-htc-one-m8s-back-to-stock-howto.3190238) for someone can share recovery.img

Comment: That's an old thread, I have already asked a few questions about M8s but nobody cares about such an old phone and all links are dead. But it seems, I found a workaround: fastboot boot twrp-3.2.3-0-m8qlul.img, run backup tool in TWRP, choose everything from there and back up to a USB OTG flash device. Hopefully, this TWRP backup will be enough to be able to restore the phone fully back to original, including recovery.

Comment: adb pull /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/recovery recovery.img